# unit conversion issue

Tags: temperature, units

I have the following equation[image]

where $ T_0(x) $ measures the temperature in Celsius at point x.

The parameter values are as follows. [image]

My question is how to handle the second term $Q_m \over \omega_bp_bc_b$, which should give a unit of Celsius right?

What conversions in these terms do i have to make in order to measure the temperature in Celsius

**I am trying to include the effect from exercises as well to this equation and modify the equation by adding a extra $Q_e\over \omega_bp_bc_b$ term. The exercise intensity $Q_e$ is measured by the unit MET. 1 MET is also defined as $58.2W/m^2$ . Can someone please tell me how to handle the units of $Q_e\over \omega_bp_bc_b$ to come up with Celsius temperature**

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. There are a couple of problems with your question: it's unclear what this complex equation is referring to, and it's unclear exactly what you're asking. It would be great if you could edit your question to remedy this.

Comment: you need to know that a watt (W) is a joule/second (J/s) and a millilitre (ml) is the same as a centimeter-cubed (cm^3) and a centimeter is 1/100 meter (m).

Comment: That second term appears to be $Q_m \over \omega_b \rho_bc_b$, not $Q_m \over \omega_bp_bc_b$.

Comment: @DanielGriscom this is bio heat  transfer equation as in http://www.academia.edu/7350650/Finite_Element_Analysis_of_One_Dimensional_Bio-Heat_Transfer_in_Human_Tissue

Comment: Great: you should add this to the question itself, which needs to be self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

Writing $(Q_m)$ (and so on) for the numerical value of the constants in the units stated,

\begin{align}
\frac{Q_m}{\omega_b \rho_b c_b}
&=
\frac{(Q_m)\mathrm W/\mathrm m^3}{(\omega_b)\frac{\mathrm{ml}}{\mathrm{ml\: s}} \times (\rho_b) \frac{\mathrm {kg}}{\mathrm m^3} \times (c_b)\frac{\mathrm J}{\mathrm{kg}\:^{\circ}\mathrm C}}
\\ & =
\frac{(Q_m)}{(\omega_b)(\rho_b)(c_b)}
\frac{\mathrm W}{\mathrm m^3}
\frac{\mathrm{ml\: s}}{\mathrm{ml}}
\frac{\mathrm m^3}{\mathrm {kg}}
\frac{\mathrm{kg}\:^{\circ}\mathrm C}{\mathrm J}
\\ & =
\frac{(Q_m)}{(\omega_b)(\rho_b)(c_b)}
\frac{\mathrm W\:\mathrm{s}}{\mathrm J}
{}^{\circ}\mathrm C
\end{align}
from the obvious cancellations. Here $1\mathrm W\:\mathrm s=1\mathrm J$, so the fraction cancels out, and you're left with ${}^{\circ}\mathrm C$ as desired.

Quick notes:

1. The notations $\mathrm J/\mathrm {kg}{}^\circ \mathrm C$ and $\mathrm {ml}/\mathrm s/\mathrm {ml}$ are *both* deprecated and should not be used, because it is not clear whether the third symbol is in the global denominator or not. In these situations one should use brackets such as $\mathrm J/(\mathrm {kg}{}^\circ \mathrm C)$ and $\mathrm {ml}/(\mathrm s\:\mathrm {ml})$ or $\mathrm J/\mathrm {kg}{}^\circ \mathrm C$ and $\mathrm {ml}/\mathrm s/\mathrm {ml}$ explicit powers, such as $\mathrm J\:\mathrm {kg}^{-1}{}^\circ \mathrm C^{-1}$ and $\mathrm {ml}\:\mathrm s^{-1}\mathrm {ml}^{-1}$. What one should definitely never do is use both notations, with the same meaning, in the same document. Wherever you got this stuff from has some pretty reprehensible dealings with units and you would do well not to imitate them.
2. While the unit $\mathrm {ml}/(\mathrm s\:\mathrm {ml})$ can sort of make sense on occasion (here, milliliters of blood perfused per milliliter of blood pumped, per second), in general it is simply better to cancel those out and leave an explicit $\mathrm s^{-1}$. Sometimes it's worth it to keep un-cancelled units of the same dimension (such as with Hubble's constant, $H_0\approx 70\mathrm {km}\:\mathrm s^{-1}\mathrm{Mpc}^{-1}$, where a $\mathrm{Mpc}$ is a length, so the whole thing simplifies to an impracticably clunky value $H_0\approx 2\times 10^{-18}\mathrm s^{-1}$ with an astronomical number in it) but otherwise it's best to cancel those out.

   Note that these are physicist opinions, and that biologists might disagree (or agree in principle but not implement them in practice). You came here to ask so this is the viewpoint you're getting.
3. It's $\rho_b$, not $p_b$ (Greek letter [rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rho)), as befits a density. Minor point but I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: I am trying to include the effect from exercises as well to this equation and modify the equation by adding a extra $Q_e\over \omega_bp_bc_b$ term. The exercise intensity $Q_e$ is measured by the unit MET. 1 MET is also defined as $58.2W/m^2$ . How would this term affect the units to result in a final value in celcius

Comment: @clarkson You're comparing apples and oranges, and that sort of naive modification is simply plain wrong. You need to look at the model that produced the equation you care about, understand it completely, and then modify it from the basic physical assumptions so it includes the physics of the new term, and work the consequences through to the conclusions. This goes beyond symbol-pushing and if you attempt a fix-it-at-home strategy then you have no guarantee that it will be correct.

Comment: Furthermore, it's not very clear what $Q_e$ is meant to be and why you expect it to have dimensions of energy use per unit area. Wikipedia defines it as the rate of energy consumption per unit of body mass (i.e. essentially in $\mathrm W/\mathrm {kg}^3$), and it is somewhat clear that the conversion to $\mathrm W/\mathrm m^2$ is only done using the body-mass-to-surface-area of an average person. The ratios of energy consumption to body mass and to body surface area are different physical quantities and will be different for different people.

Answer (score 0):

Since mL cancels with mL, J/s and N-m are compatible and therefore you should need no scaling.

Comment: Thanks . But what if I have another term being added to the equation with $Q_e \over \omega_b \rho_bc_b$ where $Q_e$ is measured in $Wm^{-2}$

Comment: @clarkson so you mean just replace $Q_m$ with $Q_e$? You can't just do that. It's no longer a conversion issue (e.g. cm instead of meters). You are changing the model. It's like substituting $E$, energy for $F$ in Newtons second law $F=ma$.

Comment: @clarkson If this is part of your question, you should add it to your question, or make it clearer so that readers will understand it better.

Comment: @clarkson It looks like you need another equation that relates metabolic heat generation with $Q_e$, whatever that stands for. I have no idea.

Comment: @docscience I am trying to include the effect from exercises as well to this equation. The exercise intensity $Q_e$ is measured by the unit MET. 1 MET is also defined as $58.2 W/m^2$ . I still keep $Q_m$ term. I am trying to modify the equation by adding the extra term $Q_e$